# setTransform with a projection

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

In the [doc of the `setTransform` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform)  , only 6 elements are passed in order to be able to do transformations to the image. However, my application finds a 3x3 matrix where the last row is different to `0 0 1` as is modifying the projection of the image.

I naively added elements to the call:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.setTransform(1, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0, 0, 99, 99, 99);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

But I'm pretty sure it's being multiplied by  `0 0 1`.

Is there a function in JavaScript that can handle this?